# mysql show data foreign key relationship and automatically add primarykeynumber by new entrie

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, inner-join

probably two simple questions but I can't think of the right terms for a search:

**Question: 1.** can I tell the database to automatically insert the primary key when creating new entries?
Means before:

`INSERT INTO guest (IDguest, firstname, lastname). VALUES('3', 'Isabell', 'ExamplewomanB');`

After:
`INSERT INTO guest (firstname, lastname) VALUES('Isabell', 'ExamplewomanB');`

Follows: -> Automatically in DB for this entry IDguest = 3.

**Question: 2.** How do I get the names/attribute entries of the linked tables instead of foreign key IDs in a relational database query?
So I want to show the name of guests where are on 2022-07-11 in.

Example DB:

Guest-Table:

| IDguest | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Otto | Exampleman |
| 2 | Anna | Examplewoman |

Room-Table:

| IDroom | roomnumber | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 | 200 |
| 3 | 101 | 50 |

Booking-Table:

| IDbooking | guestID | roomID | begin | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-11 | 2022-10-17 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-18 | 2022-07-18 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2022-07-12 | 2022-07-15 |

Is this the correct?
`SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN guest ON guest.IDguest = booking.guestID WHERE '2022-07-11' between 'begin' and 'end'`

If you need for testing db:

```
Create DATABASE house;

USE house;

CREATE TABLE guest
(
    IDguest int primary key auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(255) not null,
    lastname varchar(255) not null
);

INSERT INTO guest(IDguest, firstname, lastname)
VALUES
    ('1', 'Otto', 'Exampleman'),
    ('2', 'Anna', 'Examplewoman');


CREATE TABLE room
(
    IDroom int primary key auto_increment,
    roomnumber varchar(255) not null,
    price varchar (255) not null
);


INSERT INTO room (IDroom, roomnumber, price)
VALUES
    ('1', '100', '100'),
    ('2', '200', '200'),
('3', '101', '50');

CREATE TABLE booking
(
    IDbooking int primary key auto_increment,
    guestID INT,
    roomID INT,
    begin DATE,
    end DATE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_guest
    FOREIGN KEY (guestID)
        REFERENCES guest(IDguest),
    CONSTRAINT fk_room
    FOREIGN KEY (roomID)
        REFERENCES room(IDroom)
);

INSERT INTO booking (IDbooking, guestID, roomID, begin, end)
VALUES
    ('1', '1', '1', '2022-07-11', '2022-07-17'),
    ('2', '1', '2', '2022-07-18', '2022-07-18'),
('3', '2', '1', '2022-07-12', '2022-09-15' );
```

Comment: IF you don't supply an IDguest or supply null then IDguest will be auto generated, , no idea what Follows: -> Automatically in DB for this entry IDguest = 3. means, for your second question you are select * so all columns from all tables will be selected .. I am really unclear what this question is about since you can quite easily test it for yourself. If you have encountered problems you should explain what they are.

Comment: For 2.: My problem is that this sql-query doesn't give me a result but I don't know why, it worked with a different database structure once.
This works: Select * FROM guest, booking where '2022-07-11' between `begin` and `end`;
But this don't: SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN guest ON guest.IDguest = booking.guestID WHERE '2022-07-11' between 'begin' and 'end';

Comment: Those look like single quotes around begin and end when they should be backticks.

Comment: See `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 0):

For 2.:
My fault was not naming the table in begin and end

This should be correct:

`SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN guest ON guest.IDguest = booking.guestID WHERE '2022-07-11' between booking.begin and booking.end;`